# Loop each then display val

Tags: jquery

In my code there are three boxes and each one grabs some data from the html and uses them to do a small sum which is all fine. The problem I am having is getting it to loop.

What I want it to do is loop each section with the below jQuery and output the correct value. Right now what its doing is sort of just bundling it all together.

Then once it's all complete take the value from each .this-total and add them together to get a total value in `#total`

It works fine for just one but when I try to create a loop it fails.

I am not looking for a JavaScript alternative or a change to the HTML I'm experimenting with jQuery and any help would be much appreciated.

```js
var ded = 841;
var grid = 196;
var sum = parseFloat($('#mixers .mix-value').text()) / ded;
var percent = parseFloat($('#mixers .amount').text()) / 100;


$('#mixers .this-total').each(function(index) {
  $(this).val('£' + ((grid * percent) * sum).toFixed(2));
});

var total = parseFloat($('#mixers .this-total').val());

$('#total').each(function(index) {
    $(this).val( total );
});
```

```css
form {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
form input {
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
#mixers {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
section {
  padding: 5px 35px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="mixers">

  <section class="infora">
    <h2>Title A</h2>
    <p class="price"><span class="amount">17.95</span>
    </p>
    <div class="mix-value">70</div>
    <form>
      <input class="this-total" value="Price" readonly>
    </form>
  </section>

  <section class="infora">
    <h2>Title B</h2>
    <p class="price"><span class="amount">11.95</span>
    </p>
    <div class="mix-value">20</div>
    <form>
      <input class="this-total" value="Price" readonly>
    </form>
  </section>

  <section class="infora">
    <h2>Title C</h2>
    <p class="price"><span class="amount">13.62</span>
    </p>
    <div class="mix-value">10</div>
    <form>
      <input class="this-total" value="Price" readonly>
    </form>
  </section>

</div>

<form>
  <input id="total" value="Price" readonly>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this mate:

```
var ded = 841;
var grid = 196;
var grandTotal = 0;

$('#mixers .this-total').each(function (index) {
    var percent = parseFloat($(this).closest(".infora").find(".mix-value").text())/ded;
    var sum = parseFloat($(this).closest(".infora").find(".amount").text())/100;

    var total = ((grid * percent) * sum).toFixed(2);
    grandTotal = parseFloat(grandTotal) + parseFloat(total);

    $(this).val('£' + total);
});

$("#total").val('£' + grandTotal);
```

See js fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/29ynmu6o/4/

Is that what you're after?